# Software for implementing Quantum Machine Learning

Tags: resource-request, simulation, machine-learning

I want to have a software product specifically suited for Quantum Machine Learning. Please help me with a list of software product which has been designed specifically for implementing Quantum Machine Learning Algorithms. Currently, most of the packages are about hybrids like Pennylane and Qiskit are like generic interfaces through which quantum hardware can be accessed. I am looking for a high-level package which can make it easy to simulate QML, so that we can bring QML to audience with little understanding of Quantum Computing.